# PDO Not Found - Centos7 PHP7.1

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, server, centos

I am a server newbie so please bare my foolishness.

This is more a Server problem (I think) rather than a Laravel problem, but my website is based on Laravel5.4 so Just FYI.

I am currently using Google Cloud Platform to set up a VM which seemingly works as any others.

Currently installed:

- Centos 7
- mariadb
- Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
- php71

so i put my website folder into `/var/www/html/mywebsitefolder`

I set up mysql database and configure my website config for database set up and tried to run `php71 artisan migrate` at this point. And it throws the following errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in
>   /var/www/html/soyegg/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Co
>   nnection.php on line 1200 In Connection.php line 1200:
>                               Class 'PDO' not found

which i researched and said php-pdo needed to be installed so I ran the following line in cli:

```
yum install php-pdo
yum install php-pdo_mysql
```

however the error still persists.

Then I further researched and said I need explicitly stated extension in `php.ini` in order to use them. But when I check my `php.ini` for php71 it doesn't involve any line looks any like the following which others said they are supposed to be added into `php.ini`:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I am noob so I guess php71 doesn't play extension like this? But I still added it somewhere in `php.ini` where it comments about extension.

Then more errors threw out.

Please Let me know what is going on.

EDIT:
Thanks for Daniel, after running `yum install php-mysqlnd` the following error shown:

```
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached
> hostfile  * base: mirror.team-cymru.com  * epel: mirror.steadfast.net 
> * extras: mirror.team-cymru.com  * remi-safe: mirror.team-cymru.com  * updates: mirror.genesisadaptive.com Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Conflict: php-mysql-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 conflicts php-mysqlnd
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: php-mysql conflicts with php-mysqlnd-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64  You could try using --skip-broken to
> work around the problem
> ** Found 12 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows: 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-14.el7_5.x86_64 has missing requires of
> NetworkManager-libnm(x86-64) = ('1', '1.10.2', '14. el7_5')
> 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-16.el7_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with
> 1:NetworkManager-1.10.2-14.el7_5.x86_64
> binutils-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with
> binutils-2.27-27.base.el7.x86_64 gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64 is a
> duplicate with gnupg2-2.0.22-4.el7.x86_64
> google-cloud-sdk-207.0.0-1.el7.noarch is a duplicate with
> google-cloud-sdk-204.0.0-1.el7.noarch
> google-cloud-sdk-208.0.1-1.el7.noarch is a duplicate with
> google-cloud-sdk-207.0.0-1.el7.noarch
> google-cloud-sdk-208.0.2-1.el7.noarch is a duplicate with
> google-cloud-sdk-208.0.1-1.el7.noarch
> google-cloud-sdk-209.0.0-1.el7.noarch is a duplicate with
> google-cloud-sdk-208.0.2-1.el7.noarch httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.x86_64
> has missing requires of httpd-tools = ('0', '2.4.6', '80.el7.centos')
> httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with
> httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.x86_64
> selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch has missing requires
> of selinux-policy = ('0', '3.13.1', '192.el7
> _5.3') selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch is a duplicate with selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.no arch
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
yum install php71w-mysqlnd
```

If the installation is executed by this command then it will be added automatically to `php.ini` configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a branch of MySQL so install the PHP 7.1 version of the PDO driver for MySQL by running

```
yum install php7.1-mysql
```

This should automatically add it to the loaded configuration `php.ini` file.

Comment: it says `No package php7.1-mysql available.`

Comment: oh i think i installed `php-mysql.x86_64` for some reason as i checked `yum list installed | grep mysql`

Comment: Try `yum install php-mysqlnd`

Comment: So your problem is that you have php-mysqlnd installed, but for PHP version 5.4 (php-mysqlnd-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64) - however you use PHP version 7.1. Try to remove the old package with `yum remove`. You should then be able to add the new

Comment: Am I right to say that i needa run `yum remove php-mysql.x86_64` and then `yum install php-mysqlnd`?

Comment: hmm I tried it anyway but the PDO not found problem still persists.